# Open CV Haar cascade training can't be trained

Tags: opencv

hello I'm trying to develop a haar cascade classifiers, I was able to run the basic example with detection of cars, so I tried to identify a fruit, I download some images of pears and then generate the positive file and then the vector file, until this point everything is ok, I tested the vector file with the command:

```
opencv_createsamples -vec vector.vec
```

so I tried to generate the xml cascade classifier wtih the next command and options:

```
opencv_traincascade -data images/cascade -vec vector.vec -bg bg.info -precalcValBufSize 2048 -precalcIdxBufSize 2048 -numPos 24 -numNeg 450 -numStages 10 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -w 24 -h 24
```

I get the next error:

```
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: images/cascade
vecFileName: vector.vec
bgFileName: bg.info
numPos: 24
numNeg: 450
numStages: 10
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 2048
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 2048
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 24
sampleHeight: 24
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.999
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: BASIC

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   24 : 24
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
Cascade classifier can't be trained. Check the used training parameters.
```

I wasn't able to find the error... is there an opencv guru that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I just solved it:

You should give for -numPos and -numNeg a number slightly lower than your total positive and negative samples, around 80% of that.

E.g. if you have 24 positive images, give -numPos 18.

Also, 24 positive samples is way too low. Try to increase it to at least 200.